# How to format a number with specified level of precision?

Tags: r, format

I would like to create a function that returns a vector of numbers a precision reflected by having only *n* significant figures, but without trailing zeros, and not in scientific notation

e.g, I would like

```
somenumbers <- c(0.000001234567, 1234567.89)
myformat(x = somenumbers, n = 3)
```

to return

```
[1] 0.00000123  1230000
```

I have been playing with `format`, `formatC`, and `sprintf`, but they don't seem to want to work on each number independently, and they return the numbers as character strings (in quotes).

This is the closest that i have gotten example:

```
> format(signif(somenumbers,4), scientific=FALSE)
[1] "      0.000001235" "1235000.000000000"
```

Comment: Also, `options(digits=5)` may be useful for some cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the signif function to round to a given number of significant digits.  If you don't want extra trailing 0's then don't "print" the results but do something else with them.

```
> somenumbers <- c(0.000001234567, 1234567.89) 
> options(scipen=5)
> cat(signif(somenumbers,3),'\n')
0.00000123 1230000 
>
```

Answer (score 5):

`sprintf` seems to do it:

```
sprintf(c("%1.8f", "%1.0f"), signif(somenumbers, 3))
[1] "0.00000123" "1230000"
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
myformat <- function(x, n) {
    noquote(sapply(a,function(x) format(signif(x,2), scientific=FALSE)))
}
```

Comment: that works nicely, but I would like for it to return a vector of numbers