# How to format numbers in R, specifying the number of significant digits but keep significant zeroes and integer part?

Tags: r, formatting, number-formatting

I've been struggling with formatting numbers in R using what I feel are very sensible rules. What I would want is to specify a number of significant digits (say 3), keep significant zeroes, and also keep all digits before the decimal point, some examples (with 3 significant digits):

```
1.23456 -> "1.23"
12.3456 -> "12.3"
123.456 -> "123"
1234.56 -> "1235"
12345.6 -> "12346"
1.50000 -> "1.50"
1.49999 -> "1.50"
```

**Is there a function in R that does this kind of formatting? If not, how could it be done?**

I feel these are quite sensible formatting rules, yet I have not managed to find a function that formats in this way in R. As far as I googled this is not a duplicate of many similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225920/how-to-format-a-number-with-specified-level-of-precision)

*Edit:*

Inspired by the two good answers I put together a function myself that I believe works for all cases:

```
sign_digits <- function(x,d){
  s <- format(x,digits=d)
  if(grepl("\\.", s) && ! grepl("e", s)) {
    n_sign_digits <- nchar(s) - 
      max( grepl("\\.", s), attr(regexpr("(^[-0.]*)", s), "match.length") )
    n_zeros <- max(0, d - n_sign_digits)
    s <- paste(s, paste(rep("0", n_zeros), collapse=""), sep="")
  }
  s
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`format(num,3)` comes very close.

```
format(1.23456,digits=3)
# [1] "1.23"
format(12.3456,digits=3)
# [1] "12.3"
format(123.456,digits=3)
# [1] "123"
format(1234.56,digits=3)
# [1] "1235"
format(12345.6,digits=3)
# [1] "12346"
format(1.5000,digits=3)
# [1] "1.5"
format(1.4999,digits=3)
# [1] "1.5"
```

Your rules are not actually internally consistent. You want 1234.56 to round down to 1234, yet you want 1.4999 to round up to 1.5.

**EDIT** This appears to deal with the very valid point made by @Henrik.

```
sigDigits <- function(x,d){
  z <- format(x,digits=d)
  if (!grepl("[.]",z)) return(z)
  require(stringr)
  return(str_pad(z,d+1,"right","0"))
}

z <- c(1.23456, 12.3456, 123.456, 1234.56, 12345.6, 1.5000, 1.4999)
sapply(z,sigDigits,d=3)
# [1] "1.23"  "12.3"  "123"   "1235"  "12346" "1.50"  "1.50"
```

Comment: Hmm, I believe your solution does not treat, for example, 0.5 or 0.005 in the way I intended. `sigDigits(0.00500, 3)` results in `0.005` while I think it should result in `0.00500`. IO've edited my question with an answer inspired by yours that I think (hope) works for all cases. :)

Comment: `format(.0001,digits=3)` also returns `"1e-04"`.

Answer (score 2):

As @jlhoward points out, your rounding rule is not consistent. Hence you should use a conditional  statement:

```
x <- c(1.23456, 12.3456, 123.456, 1234.56, 12345.6, 1.50000, 1.49999) 
ifelse(x >= 100, sprintf("%.0f", x), ifelse(x < 100 & x >= 10, sprintf("%.1f", x), sprintf("%.2f", x)))
# "1.23"  "12.3"  "123"   "1235"  "12346" "1.50"  "1.50"
```

It's hard to say the intended usage, but it might be better to use consistent rounding. Exponential notation could be an option:

```
sprintf("%.2e", x)
[1] "1.23e+00" "1.23e+01" "1.23e+02" "1.23e+03" "1.23e+04" "1.50e+00" "1.50e+00"
```

Comment: Well, the indented usage is for nice formatting of numbers. I'm not a huge fan of scientific notation. Thank you for both you answers which I would accept if I could. I flipped a coin and jihoward won.

Comment: @jlhoward's edited answer with the function solves the issue for a wider range of numbers. It will be helpful for others wanting something similar so it deserves to be the accepted answer =)

Answer (score 0):

```
sig0=\(x,y){
  dig=abs(pmin(0,floor(log10(abs(x)))-y+1))
  dig[is.infinite(dig)]=y-1
  sprintf(paste0("%.",dig,"f"),x)
}

> v=c(1111,111.11,11.1,1.1,1.99,.01,.001,0,-.11,-.9,-.000011)
> paste(sig0(v,2),collapse=" ")
[1] "1111 111 11 1.1 2.0 0.010 0.0010 0.0 -0.11 -0.90 -0.000011"
```

Or the following is almost the same with the exception that 0 is converted to `0` and not `0.0` (`fg` is a special version of `f` where the digits specify significant digits and not digits after the decimal point, and the `#` flag causes `fg` to not drop trailing zeroes):

```
> paste(sub("\\.$","",formatC(v,2,,"fg","#")),collapse=" ")
[1] "1111 111 11 1.1 2.0 0.010 0.0010 0 -0.11 -0.90 -0.000011"
```